# Merge SObjects other than accounts, contacts, or leads

Tags: apex, merge

Standard Database.merge() method supports merging of only accounts, contacts, or leads.

Is there any this functionality can be used for other objects.
I was trying to merge opportunities and got following exception.

> Merge failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0069000000SJogJAAT;
>   first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, common.exception.SfdcSqlException:
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 14:

Can any explain me how can I merge opportunities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_merge.htm) is pretty explicit, and you mentioned it in your own post:

> Only leads, contacts, and accounts can be merged.

---

Writing your own merge function is highly complicated, and you will probably need to work on it on your own and come back here with more specific questions.

Some aspects to consider:

- You have to reparent child records. This might not even be possible for some `Master-Detail` relationships if they are not configured to allow it.

  - Even if you can reparent every relationship, you have to do a separate query for each one. You could reduce governor limit consumption by writing a helper to consolidate your queries.
  - Similar to above, you will need to add one `DML Operation` per relationship, possibly less if you implement a helper.
- You have to determine which fields to map. You could dynamically determine the collection of all writeable fields, but you may prefer another solution such as using a `Field Set` to limit the scope.
- [Transaction Control](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_transaction_control.htm) is going to need special attention.

Given the above, a generic `merge` function would be challenging to write effectively. You may want to write a targeted method that supports one specific `sObjectType`.